# Creating weekly table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-web-developer

I have an application where I set a weekly target for my employees. I also need to update target achieved by each daily. So that I can compare with set target. I need something like this:

```
sr|emp |weekly_tgt |19.11.11 |20.11.11|21.11.11|22.11.11|23.11.11|24.11.11|
```

I googled the problem and found some scheduler and event manager. But do I need to use those or there is some easier way to achieve it? If I am to use those which one should I ? I am using SQL Server for database.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not have a table like `sr | empid | WeekStartDate | TargetAchived` instead.

Comment: then how can i insert their daily achievement.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two tables: 1 to record the weekly target, 1 to record daily target.

```
create table weekly_target (
  id smallint PRIMARY KEY,
  emp smallint,
  startweek date,
  target decimal(3,2))

create table daily_target (
  id smallint PRIMARY KEY,
  emp smallint,
  [date] date,
  target_value decimal(3,2))
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/838ba/4)

Comment: Thank you it helped .But here you are comparing daily achievement with weekly . I want to add whole weeks achievement and then compare with weekly target.

Comment: @user1097946 You were looking for a table structure and that is what I provided. A simple modification of the query will accomplish what you are looking for.